# Need to go back to specified tab from different activity instead of default 1st tab

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs, android-tablayout, floating-action-button

I created fragment tabs in TabLayout. I click on my FloatingActionButton, it takes me to an empty activity, then I have a "Back" button in that empty activity and I want that back button to take me to the tab that I was on when I click the FloatingActionButton.

Right now, all I get is return to the default 1st tab only no matter which of the 3 tabs I was on.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;


private ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);



     // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    //setup the viewPager adapter
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    final TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);



    final FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BroadcastPage.class);
            //Go To Log In XML File
            startActivity(startIntent);

            Intent welcome = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BroadcastPage.class);


            finish();

        }
    });


}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {

        // launch settings activity
        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, SettingsActivity.class));


        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



  public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch(position) {


   case 0:
    World activity_world_tab = new Worldtab();
   return activity_world_tab;


   case 1:
    BroadcastTab activity_broadcast_tab = new BroadcastTab();
   return activity_broadcast_tab;



case 2:
    GroupsTabBar activity_groups_tabbar = new GroupsTabBar();
    return activity_groups_tabbar;


            default:
               return null;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 3;
    }



    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {



        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                return "";
            case 1:
                return "SECTION 2";
            case 2:
                return "SECTION 3";
        }
        return null;

        }
      }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove **finish()** on the click listener of your fab button. That should solve your issue. That's how your onClickListener for the fab button should look:

```
fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {


        Intent startIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BroadcastPage.class);
        //Go To Log In XML File
        startActivity(startIntent);

        Intent welcome = new Intent(MainActivity.this, BroadcastPage.class); //you could erase this line since its not really needed

    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks I tried it but it doesn't solve my problem. It doesn't change anything actually

Comment: I think there's some problem with the conditions in your onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) function. 

savedInstanceState.getInt("PAGE 0") should be replaced by savedInstanceState.getInt("PAGE")

Comment: There may be something wrong with all the code associated with saved and restore instance states